# Is this how we want to treat newcomers?

Tags: discussion, meta, welcoming

I'm not totally sold on the whole "Stack Overflow is a mean site" thing. But yesterday a new user posted a frustrated question to Meta asking why every question is either closed or ignored, and they were promptly piled-on, tone-policed, and had that question closed and deleted.

I'll totally admit that the meta post was on the hostile side, but it was clearly out of frustration. Instead of having it read in good faith, they were asked - in the most upvoted comment - "Mind rewording your question to sound...less confrontational?". The commenter apparently understood the question and was probably capable of answering it, but chose instead to ask them to change the way it "sounds" because it was too "confrontational". Very welcoming, thanks for your help!

Then after 29 downvotes in the first hour, a moderator steps in with "I've closed this, as it reads like a rant and it's based on false assumptions". Yes, it does read a little ranty. Or if you want to be more charitable, it reads like it was written by someone who had a frustrating experience on the site. Maybe change "based on false assumptions" to "based on the limited experience of someone struggling with the site" and you'd be spot on.

I'm embarrassed to see that this is the way SO treats newcomers. Part of that is because I thought it didn't happen. I didn't take into account the fact that questions can be closed and deleted and invisible to me and the majority of users - thanks to Martijn Pieters for doing a little digging, and determining that this is a semi-regular occurrence. I think it's possible to read the question in good faith and answer it as-is; I wrote an answer that got 6 upvotes before the question was closed.

I get that people are tired, and they feel like they are doing unpaid support work. There seems to be an interesting dynamic where the users who are the most tired are still so active and quick to delete. I'm not volunteering to hand-hold or mentor every user who's had a bad experience, but I wonder if there isn't enough untapped patience to help out. The tooling support isn't very good and it probably wouldn't work out, but that's the ideal I'll try to keep in mind.

It's been pointed out that the only real question here is the mostly-rhetorical "Is this how we want to treat newcomers?". I feel like the community has had its say, so I'll leave it at that. Consider it answered.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388049/why-is-every-question-either-put-on-hold-removed-or-ignored-on-here

Comment: Maybe a 10Ker can post a screenshot with user name(s) redacted.  But otherwise hard to chime in without seeing it.  That being said rants on any website (not just SO) never go over well.

Comment: I don't know if you visit MSO every day (if not, then maybe try it), you'll find such rants every week or even every day. Most of us genuinely want to help, but all we get is blame and more blame from users who mostly don't understand how this site is supposed to work. And we're *tired*...

Comment: Yes, the effort to manage a community can be tiring

Comment: @bmm6o It's not just that. It's that OP didn't seem to be interested in getting help or learn about the site at all. This happening as often as it does is incredibly frustrating. Whatever happened to the old custom of getting aquainted with a site they're going to post on? It should be common sense to read help topics and _listen_ to users trying to explain.

Comment: @psubsee2003 here you go, I didn't bother to redact the usernames involved. We're all grown ups here, we can handle the critique / public bashing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOstF.png

Comment: @rene I liked your comment on that post; thank you.

Comment: I read that question and was struck by how easy everybody was going on OP.

Comment: @Will But it got 29 downvotes. I think that's what is being claimed as vicious.

Comment: I'm trying every day to write better and nicer comments @GeorgeStocker but to be honest it doesn't matter that you *liked* the comment. Did the comment work for the OP and did they took action to tell on twitter that they received helpful comments and an answer during their visit on Meta. That is what matters ...

Comment: @rene if everyone did what you did then there'd be evidence of us trying to reach out and be welcoming, and I thank you for modeling the behavior we want to show the world.

Comment: Can you elaborate on specific things that were embarrassing, and why?

Comment: related (possibly a duplicate): [Can SO get users to supply actual answers before negatively marking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/377582/839601)

Comment: I think flipping it around helps the perspective; is this how we want to be treated by newcomers?  Pretty sure that's an emphatic no.  And yet, here we are, on a subjected on regular basis to such rants.  Lots of people have made suggestions on how that can be alleviated, and unfortunately, none of those have come to fruition.  *Many* of those suggestions would almost entirely eliminate these rants.

Comment: This seems like more of a rant than an actual question or suggestion.

Comment: @mason Because there's been a lot of discussion already about the way newcomers are treated here, as I'm sure you know. I was never entirely convinced that there was a problem because the instances that you could point to seemed like definite outliers and real exceptions. Then yesterday, I step in to try to help someone out, and there's this interaction that 1) goes really poorly very quickly and 2) gets nuked so nobody but the newby sees it. My house is dirtier than I thought.

Comment: And I don't even know how dirty it is since it can so quickly be swept away.

Comment: @fbueckert You're definitely right - nobody wants to be subjected to a rant. Maybe I'm just taking it way less personally than everyone else? When you read it, can't you sense the author's frustration? I think the attitude of "you have to change your tone before we'll help you" leads to a downward spiral.

Comment: @EJoshuaS You have a point, though on reflection I'd say that there is a question but it's mostly rhetorical. I didn't expect so many people to conclude that, looked at objectively and outside the heat of the moment, this is as good as the interaction could have gone, we should be satisfied with it, and really it was the newby's fault.

Comment: I think you're missing the frequency of the rants, and putting all the onus on us to solve the problem.  I'm challenging that perspective; there needs to be a balance, between us, and new users.  I feel like we're *already* bending over backwards trying to accommodate them; it's high time they start working with us to help themselves, too.

Comment: @bmm6o It seems like through your subsequent comments you got my point. The community didn't treat that person poorly. Sure, they got some downvotes but those don't *do* anything. And they got asked to change their approach to one that was more likely to result in a friendly and productive result instead of accusatorial. You ever seen someone start to say something really rude, then the other person cuts them off and says "Stop. Start over"? That's what this was: a warning that they shouldn't proceed with their current course, and should come back in a more constructive tone.

Comment: From the close reason: “question does not appear to seek input and discussion from the community. If you have encountered a problem on one of our sites, please describe it in detail.”. I’d say the OP described the problem in detail and the title poses a questions. Meets all the criteria to stay open.

Comment: I went through all deleted questions posted in July that were closed before deletion, and counted those that can be qualified as rants; posts where the question asker is clearly not interested in feedback. There were, by my count, **15** such posts. *We average a full-on rant every second day*.

Comment: These are their post ids, for the enterprising 10k+ users among us: 386925 386929 387080 387109 387111 387113 387116 387439 387469 387635 387749 387840 387806 387807 387956

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Why reopen this? It's a rant, not a question or a suggestion.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Having a clear problem statement isn’t enough. By the OP’s [own admission](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388076/is-this-how-we-want-to-treat-newcomers#comment718628_388076), the question in the title is rhetorical. Exactly what input or discussion is this seeking?

Comment: @MartijnPieters here is an easily clickable list with creation and deletion dates: https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/1085386

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters. Part of what makes it awkward (for me) to talk about is that I have no insight into how frequent an occurrence it is or what the similarities are, since it quickly disappears from view.

Answer (score 59):

That wasn't really a question.  That was an all-out rant.

I'll post the entire body of the *question* for posterity's sake.

> It's really frustrating when you can't ask anything without it being
> deleted or voted down. It's also very insulting to get told that your
> question is "off-topic" even though it couldn't be more on-topic.
>
> I find this site to be on par with IRC at this point: it's basically
> not possible to get help or have anyone read your questions properly.

I *wanted* to respond to this since that's the kind of question that comes up on Meta - "Why is my question closed?"  Instead of the OP being constructive with their question, they chose to make it out like we were the aggressor in the circumstance.

I've had ***great*** success with talking with people on Meta about their deleted questions and I feel like I've at least helped *one* of them out understand their position.

Hell, I even *asked* them to fix their question!

Did they fix it?  No!  Why should I bother engaging from that point onwards?

[image: Screenshot of three comments. First Makoto asks the question asker, Lisa, if they are actually trying to understand how question closure works. Lisa says they're wondering but wishes it weren't the case. Makoto then asks Lisa to edit the question to be less confrontational.]

## Do you *get* how frustrating it is to have someone literally shout in your face about this?

They didn't want to talk about it.  They wanted a punching bag.  They don't *deserve* a punching bag.

That's not how I want to be treated by newcomers.

Comment: This is literally what I'm screaming **out loud** about.   We're the ones that have to go on the defensive here on Meta with questions like this, and somehow *we're* the assholes.   Infuriating.

Comment: +1: If Stack Exchange wants Meta to function as a customer service hotline, whose reps are content to get shouted at, then they need to start writing us all paychecks.

Comment: I know... If someone walked into the local cannery where I volunteer at and started screaming at everyone that their requests for food had been denied, and the **worst most unwelcoming thing** that anybody said to this person was "I'm not against you, but it seems you're just ranting and not looking for actual help. We can probably help you, but you need to be less confrontational," then I would be shocked at how amazingly welcoming we are.

Comment: @DavyM You forgot the malicious 29 people disagreeing with that person instead of giving him/her all the food they have. That's horrible.

Comment: "*That's not how I want to be treated by newcomers.*" (+1)

Comment: @Makoto I understand that it can be frustrating, maintaining a community is hard work. Since you were involved with the post in question and took it as a personal affront, maybe you are too close to answer objectively, but what I'm getting at is: given that this question came in, do we really think the way it was handled was optimal and represents this community in the best light? Yes, people are tired and maybe this is the result. Does that mean we can't strive for more?

Comment: @bmm6o: The OP wasn't called outside of their name, belittled, attacked and no comment on that thread directly went out of their way to exclude them. I attempted to engage, knowing full well that questions like this would be closed until they were edited into shape. I honestly feel like I bent over backwards and am still made out to be a villain.

Comment: @bmm6o What I don't get is: what was wrong with the comments on that post? It was handled very well for being a rant! I completely agree with Makoto. Commenting on meta feels like walking on eggshells lately. People were very civil in those comments, how were those comments unfriendly? What were they supposed to look like?

Comment: @bmm6o  sure, we can strive for more. But how much more do you want? It was handled better then many other posts. It got an answer, helpful comments (at least by the standards of one mod) and got closed and down voted to signal to other (meta) visitors: this post isn't that useful to look at. The full Q/A model in all its glory. There is only one thing missing. An OP that says: *Thanks, that was helpful*, if not in comments, then in an accept vote. It needs two to tango.

Comment: You're right, it did get an answer. Is that an important distinction for you? Would you VTC only if an answer has been posted?

Comment: @bmm6o I'm the most evil of all close voters, so no. Close vote first, talk later is my motto. YMMV

Comment: @bmm6o you seem to be acting very similar to the other OP before - you are refusing to answer pertinent questions. You are merely less aggressive than them yet as unwilling to engage what *should* have been done. So, to me at least, it seem you're only here to throw blame without trying to improve anything.

Comment: @rene Yeah, that sounded like I snarky question, but I meant it earnestly. It's awkward to talk about since the only reason I took note of the fate of the question is that I wrote an answer before it was deleted. Therefore this doesn't fit the criteria and any others that do are invisible to me.

Comment: @VLAZ Sorry, there's a lot coming my way. What do you think I'm refusing to answer?

Comment: @bmm6o In all honestly the meta regulars should really leave those questions alone. *Ignoring is often the best response* paraphrasing  what a CM once said. For me personally when I get involved it feels like defeat when it doesn't turn out the way I hope. Only to find myself defeated for a second time. It so frustrating to try so frigging hard with only 0,015% of the SO users to make this Meta site work only to find time after time after time that I'm doing it all wrong, that I'm the problem, that I have to be ashamed of myself and what not. It is fine. Let's move on.

Comment: @bmm6o why were the people who commented wrong when they *didn't* belittle anybody, or call the OP names, or act hostile in any other way. But more importantly, how would they have done it better. As I said already - what *should* have been done. All you've said is they were wrong to do what they did and never why or how this could be improved. Despite being asked these questions many times, your only answer so far has been to just go back at square one - claiming people were wrong.

Comment: @VLAZ I guess my perspective is that it's possible to simply give the OP some guidance without demanding changes to the wording of the question.

Comment: It's true nobody belittled the OP or called them names, though that is a very low bar to clear.

Comment: @bmm6o:  Enlighten me on where I made a *demand*.  Furthermore, from a copy-edit perspective, it makes sense to ask for changes to the question. What else are we to do - accept the tone that the OP has decided to rant at us in and work from there?  If there was something suitable in that post which could've been edited in, the OP should've been the one to do it there and then.  It would have at least diffused the situation and signaled that they genuinely wanted to engage and learn.

Comment: @bmm6o and what would that be? And a parallel question - why is changing the wording bad? After all, the question *was* bad - it was a rant more than anything, so surely any *good* guidance would towards amending that. Unless your suggestion is to accept shouting at from the asker as if it's fully deserved. Something you distinctly disapprove of when it's pointed the other way.

Answer (score 16):

I've said here on meta before but I'll say it again, if people can't/won't/don't take the time to understand how SO operates why are we obligated to hold their hand and "be nice"?

I put the "be nice" in quotes simply because that's a subjective description. What you think is being nice may very well be different than what I think it is. But the way SO operates does have a fairly specific set of rules and guidelines so people should be expected to follow them.

Comment: Not everyone has the time to read our *fine* manual, especially since most of the master copies are in a separate tome on a completely different site.  *Some* hand holding is required.

Comment: If they don't have time they should make time IMO though it is indeed NOT an easy task to find everything. But almost every "bad" question that shows up gets one or more helpful links to the very things that people need.

Answer (score 4):

Contrast the tone and content of the original contribution that's the topic of this question with that of a [more recent one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388335/unable-to-understand-the-reason-of-getting-down-voted#388335).

My opinion is that *rewarding* temper tantrums rather than expecting and waiting for polite interaction is non-constructive for *all* parties.

If site volunteers aren't even allowed to try to interact with someone politely - as was unarguably the case in that original contribution, then perhaps the best thing is to DV, VTC and move on. Someone who's paid for providing company/site support can be subjected to the abuse, be frustrated and have nightmares.

We can concentrate on the *useful* content and enjoy what's good about SO.

Answer (score -5):

I agree and disagree with everyone.

I want to make an attempt at fixing Lisa's question.

---

I recently asked a question and it was closed as a request to find/recommend a tool or library. I disagree that my question is off-topic.

I find using the site frustrating because it seems like I can't ask anything without it being deleted or voted down. It's also very frustrating to get told that your question is "off-topic" even though it looks like it can't be more on-topic.

What am I doing wrong? Why was my question closed as a find/recommendation request and how can I fix it?

---

So I agree with [George that the question was salvageable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/388077/4076315): the insulting "no one read it properly" part can be edited out, a link/quotation/description* of the question can be edited in, and the hyperbole can be changed so that it's clear that this is how the OP perceives things instead of sounding like they're making statements of fact.

However, I think that even when attempting to make a question constructive it's important to only change as much as you have to. We don't know that the OP thinks, "It's probably poorly worded", and I think an addition like that is more likely to lead to the OP getting upset. *There's some disagreement over whether it's OK to add links due to the Meta effect but it's possible to provide context in other ways.

I also disagree with the OP that Makoto's comment was unwelcoming. Telling someone how to improve their post is helpful and Makoto worded it like a request. Also, if the problem is that no one is willing to tell Lisa what's wrong with their question on Main then it isn't fair to also say Makoto was unwelcoming for explaining what was wrong with Lisa's question on Meta.

Furthermore, we can't expect everyone to be able to make a good edit. I fully expect to get comments pointing out issues with my version of Lisa's question as well. I think it's reasonable that when someone sees something that needs editing but can't figure out how to make the change that they leave a comment for the OP instead.

Comment: The main point I take umbrage with to your edit is that you *keep* the whole "this is insulting" rant part which adds negative value to the discussion.  George did the same thing.  I did mention - you have to understand that the *intent* of the post was to rant, not to seek help.   In the comments they had an opportunity to actually clarify their position, but they didn't edit their question.  **We don't exist to edit questions like this on the OP's behalf.** We can clarify a message, but it's hard to clarify "I hate this place because y'all's negative" any better than what the OP did.

Comment: @Makoto I actually meant to change "insulting" to "frustrating", so that was a mistake I'll fix in a moment. But I'm not suggesting that you were obligated to edit it at all, much less that anyone exists to do so.

Answer (score -8):

Problem:-
People are not behaving properly with moderators.

Source of the problem:-
Unhappy people

Fault of moderator:- No

Number of people behaving like this:- Very few. Rest are all good.

Solution:- The very few people who behave like this should undertake behavior therapy. Maybe you are angry or sad or whatever but "behavior is important".

Comment: Is that last paragraph really warranted? We never had to put users down with that wording, and it does seem to hit the CoC borderline.

Comment: @E_net4 edited the answer

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding exactly whom you're referring to.  It sounds like a sideways attack, and seems incredibly dismissive.

Answer (score -28):

If people only came here on their best days this place would be pretty quiet. If things are going well there's very little reason to visit meta. We can either close the door on them, or say, "Yea, we get you're frustrated", and help them fix it, thereby turning them from an enemy to an ally; and also that would point to the powers that be that meta is serious about welcoming new users and trying to constructively improve Stack Overflow's image and align with its goals. That's a win-win-win in my book.

From the new person's perspective, they don't realize the effort we want them to put in to ask a good question on meta; and I think because this community has been around for so long we've forgotten that we're going to get new people every day and we can't summarily dismiss newcomers without helping them understand what we need to see in order to help them.

What could have happened is the people commenting on the post could have edited the controversial parts out and included links to the question.  That would have modeled the behavior we want to see, welcomed a new user to meta, and ensured that we as a community could weigh in on their issue effectively, without 'tone policing' what they said.

[This is why editing exists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11476/16587).

Here's the question as I saw it when this question was asked:

[image: question as user posed it]

And here's my edit.  I haven't removed the feeling and sentiment the user had; but I've added the bits that make it a constructive question to answer.

[image: new question, after edits]

Some people say "this goes against the rules", but I would challenge anyone to find a rule that says not to improve a post into a constructive question.  Also, If a user is upset that their rant was edited into a constructive question, then we've done all we could; but then we could say "We tried to help you. We even modeled the right behavior", and if we've done that, who can ask any more?

Comment: In my years on Meta, I've learned what things to and not to edit.  I'm not seeing anything that could've been edited on that post that would've redeemed it.  Besides, users coming to Meta to rant are a dime a dozen, and their rants are twice as loud.  It's a lose-lose situation for everyone involved; the ranter doesn't receive release and the people being ranted to don't actually get a chance to successfully engage.

Comment: So, you're saying we should change the intent of their question by editing it?!? Also, editing in a link to their question would invoke the meta effect on it, probably compounding the user's frustration.

Comment: In my experience a ranting user is in a mindset that often prevents them from being open to suggestions. I've seen more than a few users that got really angry when their question was edited to be more neutral. Sometimes users just want to rant. Maybe it could help to lock such a question for a while before editing it.

Comment: You pulled an entire topic out of basically nowhere and completely changed the topic of the question. Any question can be improved by completely replacing it with a different question, but such edits are not allowed under the current rules.

Comment: You didn't. It's the OP that said that Makoto's comment in particular was unwelcoming.

Comment: I've seen Shog make magical edits, bringing badly written stuff into very decent shape. Always had those in mind when facing poorly received posts. Sorry, George, but this is the opposite of what I thought good edits were.

Comment: I appreciate the compliment @brasofilo, but I think George's edit is pretty reasonable here - he brings the important part of the question, de-emphasizes the less constructive aspects... There's probably still room for improvement, but undoubtedly the question is better after the edit.

Comment: I’ve had many bad days in my life. Even some on The Internet, believe it or not. But so far as I can remember I’ve never introduced myself to a bunch of strangers by insulting them. I disagree with the premise of this question. I disagree with the extent to which TPTB is asking us to bend over backwards to accommodate incivility, even outright rudeness. I disagree with the now seemingly *procedural* refusal to ever support *our* point of view.

Comment: "but I would challenge anyone to find a rule that says not to improve a post into a constructive question" It's not exactly a rule, but [Tim Post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/386617/7795130) deleted an answer which, according to him, would have needed "correcting that would mean writing a completely different answer." In that case, Shog thought of a way to correct it without making it into a completely different post, and so he undeleted it. Yet here, you've added a specific question, and centered the post around it. That's a better question, yes, but because it's completely different.

Comment: The edit also added _"Thanks for helping me out here"_, which is the kind of noise we're typically told to remove.