# Help improving my question about MySQL

Tags: discussion, specific-question, downvote-reason

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [Get specific date lists between start and end date(mentioned in DB) with a specific interval(like 7days,15days, monthly) along with other join queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57413162/get-specific-date-lists-between-start-and-end-datementioned-in-db-with-a-speci)

I am unable to understand why am I downvoted for this question. 
Yes, I am not a good writer. I tried best to make understand the query.

I was unable to place the 'code' section properly as my SQL query contains ` sign, which is normal as I have copied the code from my phpmyadimn.

Comment: First thing I see is you added screenshots of table structure instead of raw `create table` statements which would enable copy & past to reproduce your structure and try the statement.

Answer (score 12):

You need to reduce your question to its minimal expression.

There is a lot of domain-specific information in your question that is not necessary to deal with (and distracts from) your actual problem. Instead of copying-pasting your actual data-structures, create a specific example to find what's where exactly you have an issue.

The SQL query you present in your question has variables, complex expressions, interval comparisons, sub-selects, multiple joins of different types... A potential answerer needs to guess where exactly you have a problem. And since we do not have access to your DB, it's not like we can simply run the query and see what's wrong.

Start by building your query in a SQL editor with syntax checker to remove the more obvious syntax errors (Hint: there are syntax errors). From there, try to test each part of the query in isolation, until you discover which one is actually the problematic one.

If by that time you are *still* having issues, post a question about that **that issue**, with a **simplified query that shows the unexpected behaviour**.

In all likelihood, by that time you will have probably have fixed your issue on your own. Wouldn't that be awesome?

Regarding downvotes: users are not expected to explain their votes, up or down. Because of all the things I just said, users may have seen your question as unclear, poorly researched, or simply not useful for future visitors. Those are all valid reasons to downvote a question. Take it as learning experience, and your next question will be better for it.